# How to get current date with reset time 00:00 with Kotlinx.LocalDateTime?

Tags: kotlin, timezone, kotlinx-datetime

I'm using kotlinx.Clock.now() to get current date. Next I need to convert this date to LocalDateTime, here is my code:

```
Clock.System.now().toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault())
```

It works well. However, I need to get today's day, but exactly the beginning of today's day, that is 00:00:00.
Is it possible to reset the time to 00:00:00?

Comment: Note, the start of a local day is not _always_ `00:00` for every day in every time zone.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get today's date as a `LocalDate`.

You can do it the long way:

```
val now = Clock.System.now()
val tz = TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()
val today = now.toLocalDateTime(tz).date
```

Or you can simplify using [`Clock.todayIn`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/today-in.html):

```
val tz = TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()
val today = Clock.todayIn(tz)
```

With either of the above, you can now get the starting `Instant` of the day using [`LocalDate.atStartOfDayIn`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx-datetime/kotlinx.datetime/at-start-of-day-in.html).

```
val startInstant = today.atStartOfDayIn(tz)
```

From there if you need a `LocalDateTime`, you can get that as well:

```
val start = startInstant.toLocalDateTime(tz)
```

Putting it all together:

```
val tz = TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()
val start = Clock.todayIn(tz).atStartOfDayIn(tz).toLocalDateTime(tz)
```

I recommend `atStartOfDayIn`, as it will correctly return the starting point of the day - which is not necessarily `00:00`.

For example, on March 12th 2023 in Cuba (tz: `America/Havana`), the day started at `01:00`, because it was the first day of daylight saving time, and in that particular time zone, the transition occurs at `00:00`.  (In other words, the local time goes from `23:59` to `01:00` on that day.). There are many other cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

`LocalDateTime` has a constructor that takes a `LocalDate` and a `LocalTime` as arguments.

You can pass the the desired `LocalDate` to it along with `LocalTime.MIN`, which will result in a `LocalDateTime` at the specific date with a local time of `00:00:00`.

Have a look at the [sources of the kotlinx-datetime project](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime/tree/master/core/common/src)

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach doesn't account for local days where `00:00` doesn't exist, due to a DST transition.  See my answer for an example.

Comment: That's correct, unfortunately…